# jQuery.ajax() method's async option deprecated, what now?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

As of jQuery 1.8, the use of `async:false` in [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is **deprecated**.
But how many webpages have you seen with a "loading screen" while there is an ongoing AJAX communication in the background? I have probably seen thousands of them.

My case is that I am writing a mobile app that needs to load a language file. And at the beginning I load the language file and I retrieve the text of the buttons and other GUI elements from the language file.

This is really bad for me. Because if the language file is missing, the GUI shouldn't appear. So how do I solve it? Put all my code in the `success` callback? That doesn´t seem like a good coding practice to me. Can I solve it another way?

Comment: You can make new functions. And call those functions in the onSuccess handler. It's still viewable like that

Comment: @ChenKinnrot `async=false `is `sync ;)

Comment: It took me a few reads to click that. At first I was like "uh?" and then I was like "ermahgerd!"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The solution is to manually add an overlay to prevent the user to interact with the interface, and then remove it once the AJAX query is done.

```
$(function() {
    show_overlay();        

    $.ajax({
        // Query to server
    }).done(function() {
        // Verify good data
        // Do stuff
        remove_overlay();
    });
});
```

Comment: can you explain how should I manually add and remove that overlay? show_overlay() is not a function. Sorry if this question is too noob but I'm new on this.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo This is just an example. `show_overlay()` is a hypothetical function that displays an element that obscures the interface, like a div that fills the viewport with a high z-index with some content.

Comment: ok, ty for the clarification. I'm trying to deal with Jquery ContextMenu plugin, generate contextmenu sub-items depending on ajax response, so I can't apply your solution to that.

Comment: What if the function that needs to block ui is a ajax call like a grabbing html from the server and loading it with `$().html(data)`?

Comment: Instead of an overlay, you could add an "untouchable" class to the body element, e.g. `body.untouchable *{pointer-events:none !important; cursor: wait !important;}`.

Comment: What if the user uses the keyboard to interact with the UI?

Answer (score 30):

I read the [official discussion](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11013) in the ticket about the deprecation of this parameter and here is what I understood:

- The problem is that implementing [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise)s ([1](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)) for sync AJAX gives them overhead.
- There are tons of real world use cases of sync AJAX, e.g. preserving state before page unload. Therefore, this functionality will stay, but the way you use it may change.
- The nearest solution (landing in 1.8?) is to support only callbacks (but not the Promises) when `async` is `false`.

**To conclude**: Keep using `async: false` if you have to, but beware of its drawbacks (blocking of VM). Don't worry, you will be provided an alternative if this feature ever gets removed form [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: What does "preserving state before page unload" mean? I can't think of a single good use for synchronous AJAX.

Comment: @user2867288, page unload is an event, which happens when the user tries to close the browser tab/window. "Preserving state" could mean a lot of things: autosaving form data, telling the server that user interaction has completed, submitting some analytical data (e.g. how much time user has spent on the page). There really is a use case for this - that is why [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) was created. When it is has proper crossbrowser support, there is not that much need for synchronous AJAX.

Answer (score 4):

I would bet that *many* of those 1000's of pages don't actually block the UI while waiting for the AJAX call.  Instead, they probably obscure the UI with the waiting screen at the time the call is made and then remove that on a response handler.

There are many ways to obscure the UI (you could even just use a jQuery UI Dialog that's set to Modal and has no escape or close buttons), so I'll leave that decision up to you.  But the layout of the code would be something like this:

```
var someFunction = function () {

    // any pre-conditions to the logic
    // obscure the UI here

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test.html',
        success: function(data) {

            // handle the response
            // show the UI again

        },
        error: function(data) {

            // handle the response
            // show the UI again

        }
    }); 
}
```

I'm sure there are multiple ways to achieve that order of events, but that's the general idea.  Blocking the UI was never really the intent, and I imagine it was an even more difficult decision for jQuery to *include* that feature than it was to *remove* it.  It's meant to be asynchronous.

Comment: But if you really want to block the UI use the blockUI plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Comment: @Simon: Sure, if you _really_ want to.  But it's not recommended and, more often than not, is an indication that one needs to re-think one's approach.  There are probably exceptions, though I can't think of any right now.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to call your function as a callback in the success of the ajax call, and pass in the results of your ajax call.

For example:

```
function getPetInfo(petid,callback){

  $.ajax({
    url: 'get-petinfo.php',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    data: {
      cache: false,
      petid: petid
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var dataobject = JSON.parse(data);
      callback(dataobject);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why would you use ajax to get this file? Just include it using a `script` tag.

In any case, you don't put all your code in the onSuccess - instead you call a single function from there that starts your code running.

Comment: Imagining that there is some scenario where you would need to get data via ajax, the question still stands as respectable.