# How can I execute callback after multiple Ajax requests complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to execute a callback after multiple jQuery Ajax have **completed**.
In my code both Ajax requests call another function and when I try to use these functions I get `undefined`.
I think the problem has to do with using deferred/promise, but I don't know how to use them.

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tag/sites/ocean1/maker/captions/shared%20documents/Web_ComplianceCSS.txt">
<div id = "cabbage" style="font-size:10px">
  <p>Web Compliance Stats</p>
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript">
  var WebComplianceReportApp = {} || WebComplianceReportApp;
  WebComplianceReportApp.GetStatuses = (function() {
    var pub = {},
      _userId,
      _ultimateObjectHolderArr = [],
      _items = [],
      _options = {
        listName: "M_Web_Compliance",
        container: "#cabbage",
      };
    pub.init = function() {
      var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      _userId = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
      clientContext.load(_userId);
      clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getUserInfo, _onQueryFailed);
    };

    function getUserInfo() {
      _userId = _userId.get_id();
      getSpecifiedList(_options.listName, _userId);
    }

    function buildObject(results, listName) {
      _items = results.d.results;
      $.each(_items, function(index, item) {
        _ultimateObjectHolderArr.push({
          "Division": item.ParentOrg,
          "ORG": item.ORG,
          "URL": item.URL,
          "Status": item.Site_Status
        });
      });
      //createStatusView2(_ultimateObjectHolderArr);
    }

    function getSpecifiedList(listName, userId) {
      var counter = 0;
      var baseUrl = SP.PageContextInfo.get_webServerRelativeUrl() + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName;
      var url1 = baseUrl + "?$select=ParentOrg,ORG,URL,Site_Status&$inlinecount=allpages";
      var call1 = $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
      }).done(function(results) {
        buildObject(results, listName);
      }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log("Error in getting List: " + listName);
        $(_options.container).html("Error retrieving your " + listName + ". " + SP.PageContextInfo.get_webServerRelativeUrl());
      });
      var url2 = baseUrl + "?$select=ParentOrg,ORG,URL,Site_Status&$inlinecount=allpages&$skiptoken=1000";
      var call2 = $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
      }).done(function(results) {
        buildObject(results, listName);
      }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log("Error in getting List: " + listName);
        $(_options.container).html("Error retrieving your " + listName + ". " + SP.PageContextInfo.get_webServerRelativeUrl());
      });
    }

    function createStatusView2(Arr) {
        var divisionArr = [];
        var oRGArr = [];
        var divisionCount = 0;
        var oRGCount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
          if ($.inArray(Arr[i].Division, divisionArr) === -1) {
            divisionArr.push(Arr[i].Division);
            var divisionHolderElement = $("<div id='p_" + Arr[i].Division + "' class='division_row_holder'></div>");
            var divisionElement = $("<div id='" + Arr[i].Division + "' class='division_div ORG'></div>").text(Arr[i].Division);
            $("#cabbage").append(divisionHolderElement);
            $(divisionHolderElement).append(divisionElement);
          }
          if ($.inArray(Arr[i].ORG, oRGArr) === -1) {
            oRGArr.push(Arr[i].ORG);
            var orgElement = $("<div class='org_div ORG' id='" + Arr[i].ORG + "' style='font-size:10px;'></div>").text(Arr[i].ORG);
            $("#p_" + Arr[i].Division).append(orgElement);
          }
        }
      }
    //automatically fired by init
    function _onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
      alert('Request failed.\nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
    return pub
  }());
  $(document).ready(function() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
      //After the SP scripts are run, we access the WebComplianceReportApp.GetStatuses
      WebComplianceReportApp.GetStatuses.init();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this will make your code dirty, but I would use a **flag** in this case

**ex:**

```
var ajaxCalls = 0;
function checkAjaxCalls()
{
   if (ajaxCalls == 2)
   {
    //do your thing...
    //and maybe you want to reset ajaxCalls value to zero if needed...
   }
}
```

And from each Ajax response completes, increment `ajaxCalls` variable by one, and call the `checkAjaxCalls` function from both your Ajax responses.

Comment: Not dirty, but unnecessarily complex and error-prone. Just use promises.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `createStatusView();` and then call `createStatusView2();` after all of your Ajax requests are done

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  createStatusView();
  $(this).ajaxStop(function() {
    // NOTE: I did not see you use createStatusView(); in your code
    createStatusView2();
  });
});
```

Comment: I have two separate AJAX jQuery calls within a function **getSpecifiedList(listName, userId)** . After each AJAX call, I use done to call **buildObject()**, so that is 2 times. I only want the **createStatusView()** to run 1 time, after both AJAX calls complete the **buildObject()** function. So, the solution you recommended doesn't work at this time. Am I missing something in your response?

Answer (score 0):

## Method One:

This time we'll have waited for the request to **complete** instead of waiting for the request to **succeed**

```
$(".ajax-form-button-thingy").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("href"),
    type: 'GET',
    error: function() {
      throw new Error("Oh no, something went wrong :(");
    },
    complete: function(response) {
      $(".ajax-form-response-place").html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

## Method Two:

If you want to wait for *ALL* Ajax requests to complete without changing the `async` option to `false` then you might be looking for `jQuery.ajaxComplete();`

In jQuery every time an Ajax request completes the `jQuery.ajaxComplete();` event is triggered.

Here is a simple example but there is more info on `jQuery.ajaxComplete();` over [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/).

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
  $(".message").html("<div class='alert alert-info'>Request Complete.</div>");
});
```

Also you can take a look at the Ajax response by using `request.responseText` this might be useful in case you want to double check the response.

For more information about **jQuery.ajax** you can read the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: You should never ever set the `async` option to `false`.

Comment: Is there a bug, problem or issue I don't know about or is that purely opinion based?

Comment: It's effectively deprecated. And hangs the UI. You always want your networking operations be asynchronous.

Comment: I have removed the ```async``` option from my answer but I still want to understand more on this could you lead me to a article on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448011/jquery-ajax-methods-async-option-deprecated-what-now, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: @Bergi thanks for letting me know about this, appreciate it.