# How can I make a sync call with backbone fetch

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, synchronous

I need to call a fetch with a synchronous call, 
I know with jquery ajax I can use `{async: false}`
can I pass this option to fetch function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait for the collection to fetch everything in backbone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491230/wait-for-the-collection-to-fetch-everything-in-backbone)

Comment: A better question is why you need it to be synchronous. And the likely answer is that you're doing something the wrong way.

Comment: It's an edge case scenario yes.

Comment: Note that solution, suggested here, doesn't work anymore, since recent Mozilla Firefoxes don't allow async in jquery.ajax.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So the short answer is yes, 
you can simple call fetch function with param

```
{async:false}.
```

Answer (score 14):

Actually backbone fetch method internally calls ajax.
So you can pass any ajax options to backbone fetch method.

```
collection.fetch({
  // ajax options
   async: false, // by default it is true
   success: function(collection, response, options){
             console.log("success")
          },
   error: function(collection, response, options){
             console.log("error")            
          }
});
```